# VS Code custom run configuration for D

Tags: visual-studio-code, d, vscode-debugger, vscode-tasks

Is there a way to add a custom run configuration that would run a current file in the terminal?

Currently no extensions exist for debugging .d files on Visual Studio Code. I still can manually enter the compile and run command with dmd in the terminal, though this gets tedious and the commands can be forgettable. I saw that it might be possible to do this more efficiently using tasks but I haven't found any sufficient examples on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I use

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
            {
            "type": "code-d",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug D project",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "./darc-test-library"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Together with [CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb).