# Basic programming in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I program with Basic in Visual Studio Code (VSC), when I install the extensions for Apple Basic, rocket basic, or color basic, none of the code is recognized or will run.

On the portable version of VSC, I installed Apple, Rocket, and Color basic, wrote a line of simple basic code: for j = 1 to 10 step 1, print j, next j, and the code wasn't recognized or would run, just a pop-up asking if I want to install an extension for basic.

Comment: if you wouldn't use VScode but say Notepad, how would you run the program written in the notepad text file? I'm not familiar with the basic flavors you mention but you can configure in VSCode what it needs to do if you click run or debug.

Comment: See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69693135/vs-code-custom-run-configuration-for-d